# My wordpress site is using local ip to point to jquery and other files, how to fix it?

Tags: jquery, urls, localhost, footer

I installed WP on my Raspberry Pi using this guide :

https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/wordpress/

I did not do the last part about permalinks yet.

Problem is, when I navigate to my site using my local network, all works well, then I try from the internet, and it takes ages and only shows text, no styles etc. found out the reason for this was in the main file, at the bottom, near the footer it has :

```
...
```

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://192.168.X.X/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/js/skip-link-focus-fix.js?ver=20141010'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var screenReaderText = {"expand":"<span class=\"screen-reader-text\">expand child menu<\/span>","collapse":"<span class=\"screen-reader-text\">collapse child menu<\/span>"};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://192.168.X.X/wp-content/themes/twentyfifteen/js/functions.js?ver=20150330'></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Where 192.168.X.X is the IP for the Raspberry Pi, which of course a computer on the wider internet cannot see. I tried to find out where this was being set but could not find it anywhere.

Where is it located? and how do I set it to a relative path, or even better get the jquery and other scripts from a faster CDN?

Comment: This isn't necessarily WordPress related. You could use [relative URIs](http://www.webreference.com/html/tutorial2/3.html) to point to your scripts and styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WordPress, the footer scripts are enqueued using `wp_enqueue_scripts` into wp_footer(). So it is hard for you to find the direct scripts link in footer.php.

To change the path you can go to PHPmyAdmin and edit the `siteurl` and `home` fields in options table of your database.

You can include jQuery from CDN using the following code:

```
// Register Script
function custom_scripts() {

wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
wp_register_script( 'jquery', '//code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js', false, '2.1.1', false );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

}

// Hook into the 'wp_enqueue_scripts' action
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_scripts' );
```